# How can I sync /var/foo/ on one Linux machine with the same folder on another machine?

Tags: linux, synchronization

Initially [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) looked perfect but it only seems to be able to sync folders in my home directory. I want a way to sync any folder of my choosing on one system with any folder on another system.

Comment: Any reason why a network file system (like NFS) wouldn't be a good choice for your environment? Avoids the synchronization complexity in exchange for "Always has to be on the network")

Comment: I don't think an NFS is what I'm looking for because my understanding is that NFS lets you mount a remote volume, not sync two folders. I want to have two copies of the data - one local, the other remote. Rather like Dropbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a utility called [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) to do this.
 Unison is basically a 2-way rsync.
For basic usage, the command is pretty simple:

```
unison /path/to/local/directory/. ssh://remote-server/path/to/remote/directory/.
```

*(note the dots on the end, these are deliberate, and are used in case the directory names aren't the same on both systems)*

However it might be good idea to consult the [documentation](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs) as there are a lot of important arguments to consider, like how to handle when a file has been updated on both systems since the last sync (which one should be kept).